# how to remove /ver/XXX via htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess

please help to write htaccess rules for htaccess to change url 
http://mysite.com/some/some/ver/XXX
to
http://mysite.com/some/some/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you. It captures the first two `some`'s, and trims off the `ver`'s.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)/ver/([0-9]+) $1/$2 [R=301,L]
```

**Note:** Please see the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions) with regards to asking questions. ("You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on *actual problems that you face*.")